# Why is my panel not positioned correctly even after setting the boundaries?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to make a simple GUI with radio buttons and I grouped them into one panel. I wanted it positioned on the leftmost side so I used the setBounds method. Whatever numbers I put on the parameters, the panel won't move. Are panels not affected by the setBounds method? Or is there another way to position my panel. Here's the snippet of my code:

```
    JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();
    radioPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    JRadioButton Rbutton1 = new JRadioButton("Credit Card");
    JRadioButton Rbutton2 = new JRadioButton("E-Funds");
    JRadioButton Rbutton3 = new JRadioButton("Check");
    Rbutton3.setSelected(true);
    ButtonGroup Bgroup = new ButtonGroup();
    Bgroup.add(Rbutton1);
    Bgroup.add(Rbutton2);
    Bgroup.add(Rbutton3);
    radioPanel.add(Rbutton1);
    radioPanel.add(Rbutton2);
    radioPanel.add(Rbutton3);
    radioPanel.setBounds(10,50,50,40); //this is where I'm trying to position the panel with the radio buttons
    paymentPanel.add(radioPanel);
    contentPane.add(paymentPanel); //contentPane is the frame
    contentPane.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: sorry i'm kinda new here. i just learned how this "accept" thing goes, but i did something about it now. :D

Comment: The problem you're having is the fact the the `paymentPanel` is using a `LayouManager` that is overriding your settings. Despite what you might be thinking, this is a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set layout for the frame. For example:

```
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.add(paymentPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

More info about layout managers you can find here: [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: On second thought, there's a slight problem. When I used the code you gave, my paymentPanel suddenly resized to the width of my radioPanel. I tried doing this `paymentPanel.add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);` but it won't work.

Comment: Take a look at the link above ("A Visual Guide to Layout Managers") and read about selected layouts.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) which will do this for you. And I would suggest using a [GUI Builder Tool](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/), but that might not be allowed for your homework.

Answer (score 0):

You can set layout as null layout for your contentPane.

```
contentPane.setLayout(null);
```

Then your `setBounds()` will work exactly as you designed.

**Note:**

Creating containers with absolutely positioned containers can cause problems if the window containing the container is resized.

Comment: I could've done this but my professor instructed us that we use a BorderLayout for the contentPane.